# React search component with suggestion, how to select suggestion

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

I have a component Search component with suggestions. I create the suggestions by javascript. I can print all the suggestions, but how I can select the suggest element to put into the placeholder? Thanks for your response.

SEARCH COMPONENT

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "../../api/index";
import "./index.css";

export default function Search(query) {
  const [searchSchool, setSearchShool] = useState("");
  const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
  const [allSchools, setAllSchools] = useState([]);
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await api.getSchools();
      setAllSchools(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  const resultsAllSchools = !searchSchool
    ? allSchools
    : allSchools.filter(school => school.toLowerCase().includes(searchSchool));

  const handleOnclick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const lowerCase = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    setSearchShool(lowerCase);
    setShowSuggestions(true);
    if (e.target.value === "" || null) {
      setShowSuggestions(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input
          className="select"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Cerca el teu centre educatiu"
          value={searchSchool}
          ref={inputRef}
          onChange={handleOnclick}
        ></input>
        <button>
        </button>
        <ul>
          {showSuggestions &&
            resultsAllSchools.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: For the selection, add click handler for the `li` elements and update the `searchSchool ` state based on the click.

Comment: similar to this - <li key={index} title={item} onClick={() => handleSuggestionClick(item)}>{item}</li>